# What's the benefit of using Sinatra instead of RoR if I'm only need a DB and an API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra

I need to build a web service, for a mobile game, to manage the states of multiplayer games.  I need a database and an RESTful API to access it.  I'm very familiar with Ruby On Rails and was thinking of using that since I can throw together the DB and API pretty quickly.  However, since RoR is a framework for building web pages and I'm not actually building any web pages, it naturally seems like the wrong technology to use even though it would work.  As such, I'm considering using Ruby on Sinatra, but I've never used it before and I'll have to kill some time learning it.  For you Ruby gurus, is there an advantage to using Sinatra or a disadvantage to using RoR for what I'm trying to accomplish?

Thanks so much in advance for your wisdom!

Comment: Consider https://github.com/intridea/grape too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You know Rails, you don't know Sinatra. Personally I prefer the latter for things like building APIs, but there's nothing stopping you from doing it in Rails, and there's nothing intrinsically wrong with it either. Unless you want to see this as a learning opportunity for getting into Sinatra, I'd say stick with Rails. Here's some links that might be useful btw:

- [Building APIs With Rails](http://code.alexreisner.com/articles/building-apis-with-rails.html)
- [Building a Platform API on Rails](http://engineering.gomiso.com/2011/06/27/building-a-platform-api-on-rails/)

Answer (score 0):

It probably depends on your API. If you need more than just a bunch of routes then you will have to come up with your own solutions (authentication, ...).
If all you need is some RESTfulness without the added weight, Sinatra is great. All you need to know is what happens in what route and you're fine. See the Sinatra Readme which has all the information to get started.